# Get a random integer between two given values that is seedable

Tags: javascript, random-seed

I'm trying to generate a random integer between 1 and 25 on a few different devices, but want the results to be the same without having to send it across the network.

I thought of using the timestamp of hours:minutes as a seed, but can't figure out how to get a randomly generated number that uses a seed AND is between two values.

I've looked at [this](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom) but whenever I try to generate a value it just gives me back the seed as a string, and even if I got it to work I would still need to apply the seed to a random generator that is limited between two values.

Comment: You want to generate it in client-side JavaScript on different devices running different JS engines?

Comment: i give you one really random value: `4`, right the link: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Library that you linked actually works very good.

Comment: @trincot No they're all just running barebones Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example from the library that you linked - seems to work (*although I've edited it in order to cap it to the certain range*).

```js
const randGeneratorFrom = seed => {
  const generator = new Math.seedrandom(seed)
  return (min, max) => Math.floor(generator() * max) + min
}

const now = new Date();
const seed = [now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes()].join(':')
const rand = randGeneratorFrom(seed)

// results will be the same for the given hour:minute
console.info(seed)

console.info(rand(1, 25))
console.info(rand(1, 25))
console.info(rand(1, 25))
console.info(rand(1, 25))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/seedrandom/3.0.1/seedrandom.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. For some reason it wouldn't let me use the external link so I just copied the Javascript to a new file.